# null/empty-string first last

Tags: sql

In a lot of SQL dialects, they support the `[NULLS {FIRST | LAST}]`. Why isn't their also that same extension to the `ORDER BY` for sorting empty strings, which I often find myself wanting to push to the beginning or the end. For example, in the following column:

```
`name`
NULL
"tom"
"alex"
""
"zack"
```

I could see myself wanting to sort by something like:

```
NULL
"alex"
"tom"
"zack"
""
```

In which case it would nice to be able to do:

```
ORDER BY name NULLS FIRST EMPTY_STRING LAST
```

Or both of them at the end (nulls before empty string):

```
ORDER BY name NULLS LAST EMPTY_STRING LAST
```

Is there a construction like that in SQL? Or it only allows the `NULL` shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Sql server you can control the order with a xx_BIN collation.  For example `varchar` column, NULLs first, empty strings last:

```
order by name + char(0xff) collate Latin1_General_Bin
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `NULLIF`:

```
ORDER BY NULLIF(name, '') NULLS LAST
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server does not have an empty string last function. You can either cast empty strings as NULL or you will need to create a custom sort.

```
--This will treat blank values as NULLs
ORDER BY
    CASE
        WHEN name = '' THEN NULL
        ELSE name
        END NULLs LAST
```

or

```
--This custom order will put blanks first and nulls last
ORDER BY
    CASE
        WHEN name = '' THEN 1
        ELSE 2
        END
    ,name NULLs LAST
```